# An old movie about a liquid that melts people

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This is a movie I watched when I was younger. I saw this movie in the early 80's, and I think it was produced in the seventies.

There is a policeman who finds a corpse that looks like minced meat. I mean, the body is intact, but the face is like meat paste. It's like making a 'hamburger-melts' people. He discovers that there is a liquid with a virus placed inside of guns of a gang, a water pistol.

A woman has boxes full of virus in the form of white powder. The gang is smuggling this white powder. That powder is used to make the liquid fired from the water pistols.

There is a chase scene in which the policeman ties an iron door with ropes and attaches it to a motorcycle. Then he drives the motorcycle, pulls the rope, opens the door, and runs away.

Comment: What really is "mined meat" here? Is it like the pie? Or do you simply mean, all ground up, like hamburger or something?

Comment: I saw this movie in the early 80's... The guns belong to a gang. She has boxes full of virus in the form of white powder

Comment: I mean, the body is intact, but the face is like meat paste. It's like making a hamburger

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you'd mind checking the list of things at the accepted answer on [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and editing your post accordingly as long as you have the information to do so, it would really help us answer!

Comment: @releseabe - "minced" is the British equivalent term for "ground", while "Hamburger" to a Brit would literally mean a patty.

Comment: @Alaadoom - So did the gang shoot people with the guns to infect them with the virus? And, if so, was the viral liquid contained within bullets, or was the liquid fired directly, like from a water pistol?

Comment: a water pistol..As I remember

Comment: There's a few melting bits on https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ImMelting (TV Tropes), but nothing that seems to match your description. My first thought was something in the *Robocop* genre, but nothing is matching.

Comment: "Then he drives the motorcycle, pulls the rope, opens the door, and runs away." - this is confusing. When he pulls the rope, does the door fall off the motorcycle? Or is he using it as a weapon by releasing the door into someone while its moving? Or is it opening and forming a magical door allowing him to walk into a different building or something?

Comment: As far as I remember, the door is iron with two leaves. Like garden doors. Somehow when he drove the motorcycle to the door, the rope pulled him in and it opened